# How to parse used route version to access Flask-Restful endpoint

Tags: parsing, flask, flask-restful

I am developing a Flask RestFul API and would like to create different versions of an endpoint.

This is how I am doing it:

```
from flask_restful import Api
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(MyResource, 
    '/v0/my_end_point',
    '/v1/my_end_point'
    endpoint='my_end_point')

from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
class MyResource(Resource):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        assert db_session.is_active

    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
```

I would like to know if there is an elegant way to distinguish which version/route was used in the request, so I can give the proper treatment to each version. If the route was `v0` or `v1`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best approach, since the `version` becomes irrelevant to the route validation and you'll need to make some validations inside the resource, but it looks elegant to me.

```
from flask_restful import Api
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(MyResource, 
    '/<version>/my_end_point',
    endpoint='my_end_point')

from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
class MyResource(Resource):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        assert db_session.is_active

    def get(self, version):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        if version == 'v0':
           #do something
        else if version == 'v1':
           #do another thing
        else:
           #alert the user the version is incorrect
```